# Python is unexpectedly iterating over each element in a list twice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

In the function down below, I am trying to normalize prices (converting them to percentage differences from the starting price) in dataframes contained in a list of dataframes. Each dataframe has two columns: date and price.

```
    def normalize_windows(window_data: List[DataFrame]):

        starting_price = window_data[0]['price'].values[0]

        for window in window_data:
           for index, row in window.iterrows():
               window.at[index, 'price'] = (row['price'] / starting_price) - 1
            
        return window_data
```

Right now, when I debug the code in python, each dataframe in the list gets looped over twice thus, making all values a bit more or less -1.

[image]

Is there an unexpected behavior about the way I am looping that I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate:

```
>>> df
   price
0     12
1     15
2     10
3     12
4     12
5     18
6     11
7     12
8     15
9     10
```

```
>>> df['price'] / df.iloc[0]['price'] - 1
0    0.000000
1    0.250000
2   -0.166667
3    0.000000
4    0.000000
5    0.500000
6   -0.083333
7    0.000000
8    0.250000
9   -0.166667
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

```
def normalize_windows(window_data: List[DataFrame]):

    starting_price = window_data.iloc[0]['price']
    window_data = (window_data['price'] / starting_price - 1)
            
    return window_data
```